# Undefined variable: curl_setopt

Tags: php, android, firebase, curl, post

I'm trying to send notification to android app by FCM and using curl in my code , the code is working on php5 (on my local xampp) but when I'm trying that on php7.2 (on VPS) this error appears

> Undefined variable: curl_setopt in **/var/.../sqlite.php** on line **305**
> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /var/.../sqlite.php:305

and here is my code for that part :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

and the Line 305 is

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
```

anyone know how can I fix this?
any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the content of $fcmUrl?

Comment: $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

Comment: on a phpinfo() call do you have curl installed?

Comment: yes it's installed and doesn't error on curl_init() function

Comment: My guess is that you don't have curl_setopt function installed on your php version

Comment: i think it's about "Function name must be a string" error but I don't know what should I do with that

Comment: are you sure this is the code running? how do the lines around your snippet look like? if you run just this block do you have the same error?